# Reading formatted multi-lines in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting, scanf

I would like to read some formatted data in python. The format of the data is something similar to this:

```
00:00:00
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

00:00:02
3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3
```

I could successfully simulate the reading in C/C++ using the forward code:

```
int main()
{
    string hour;
    int x0,y0,z0, x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2;

    while(cin >> hour)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d\n%d %d %d\n%d %d %d\n", &x0, &y0, &z0, &x1, &y1, &z1, &x2, &y2, &z2);
        cout << hour << endl; //check the reading
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that i cannot find some Python's method that read a formatted multi-line string as simple as the scanf can. Some examples from np.genfromtxt got near to what a needed, as some from struct.unpack, but my skills wasn't enough to make it works right with the multi-lines.
I could probably use split() with some readline to get exactly the formatted data, but it driving me nuts that a program in C/C++ would be simpler than on in Python. Is there any way to do something similar to the C/C++ code in Python?

---

Here is the answer after the Joril's help:

```
from scanf import sscanf
import sys

data = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line != '\n':
        data += line
    else:
        print sscanf(data, "%s\n%d %d %d\n%d %d %d\n%d %d %d\n")
        data = ''
```

And as output i got something like:

```
('00:00:00', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
('00:00:02', 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#is-there-a-scanf-or-sscanf-equivalent) says:

> Is there a scanf() or sscanf() equivalent?
>
> Not as such.
>
> For simple input parsing, the easiest approach is usually to split the
>   line into whitespace-delimited words using the split() method of
>   string objects and then convert decimal strings to numeric values
>   using int() or float(). split() supports an optional “sep” parameter
>   which is useful if the line uses something other than whitespace as a
>   separator.
>
> For more complicated input parsing, regular expressions are more
>   powerful than C’s sscanf() and better suited for the task.

But it looks like someone made a module that does exactly what you want:
https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/scanf

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use regular expressions. Here is more or less matching code in python without loop:
    import re

```
hour = input()
res = re.match(
    r'(?P<hour>\d\d):(?P<minute>\d\d):(?P<second>\d\d)\n'  # \n'
    r'(?P<x0>\d+) (?P<y0>\d+) (?P<z0>\d+)\n'
    r'(?P<x1>\d+) (?P<y1>\d+) (?P<z1>\d+)\n'
    r'(?P<x2>\d+) (?P<y2>\d+) (?P<z2>\d+)',
    hour, re.MULTILINE)

if res:
    print(res.groupdict())
```

I would split the data into lines first and then parse though.

Comment: This works well, but i choosed [Joril's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3497/joril) as it was more similar to the C/C++ code.

Comment: @Ziul how could you? )